# Select Query issue while fetching the fields

Tags: android, sqlite

I wrote one query which select the name and designation fields based on id and then in fragment class i am calling that method which belongs to the appropriate query but unfortunately i am getting Sqlite Exception.

Database Method

```
public Employee getEmployeeName(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    String query ="SELECT  " + KEY_NAME +", " +KEY_DESIG +" FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEES+ " WHERE " + KEY_ID + "=" + id;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            employee.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            employee.setDesignation(cursor.getString(2));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return employee;

}
```

Calling from the Fragment

```
db.getEmployeeName(selectedManager);
```

Exception

```
01-07 06:02:34.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2386): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Comment: what is the exception you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column indexes are zero-based. `getString(2)` refers to the third column and your cursor has only two columns.

Change

```
employee.setName(cursor.getString(1));
employee.setDesignation(cursor.getString(2));
```

to

```
employee.setName(cursor.getString(0));
employee.setDesignation(cursor.getString(1));
```

Comment: I think there are two values will be return by the query and there is no 2nd location. Only 0th and 1st locations are available. Thank you! Hope am correct.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        employee.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
        employee.setDesignation(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESIG));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Get data from `Cursor` by using `cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN NAME)`

Comment: I was about to post the same. Where this has preference over using column indexes is readability and maintainability. What if you at some point write something with 9 indexes and you have to add a 10th between 1 and 2? A week later requirements change and you have to remove 5 and 6. It's just general bad practice in my opinion, even if it saves a few cpu cycles.